# Lightning OpenCTI: searchAndScreenPop with default values

Tags: lightning, opencti

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_searchandscreenpop_lex.htm) we should be able to make a call like this to prefill fields in the new record form:

```
sforce.opencti.searchAndScreenPop({
    searchParams:'Acme', 
    callType: 'inbound', 
    defaultFieldValues:{
        LastName: 'This is a test'
    }, 
    callback: (...args) => console.log(args)
});
```

The documentation labels the property as `defaultFieldsValue` the code snippet next to it uses `defaultFieldValues`. Neither seem to work at all though.

I was not able to prefill any fields using the documented approaches. Am I doing something wrong here / does this work for anyone else?

I'm on Summer 18, this has not been working in the previous version as well though.

Comment: The documentation also states - "If you’re noticing inconsistent behavior with the default settings of your softphone layout, edit your softphone layout to force the cache to refresh. From Setup, edit your softphone layout and save the changes. Then edit the layout again and reset the layout to the default settings."

Have you tried this?

Comment: @the_phantom yes I have. Though the problem is not with the layout itself, as opening a new record form works flawlessly. Its the `searchAndScreenPop` that does not work as described in the docs.

Comment: I had used this in classic and it used to work fine. Will have to see one in lightning.

Comment: It does indeed work in Classic, like it always did. In Lightning not so much.